# It seems that <br is finding its way into my JSON responses

Tags: java, php, android, json

**org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

From what I can gather.. I am receiving a string that is contaminated with HTML and I have no idea why!

I've spent a few hours researching this issue on the internet but have not found any responses that match.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**New Logcat response:**

```
   02-29 19:09:05.378 10027-10027/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-29 19:09:05.501 10027-10027/k.unionapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/k.unionapp-2/lib/x86
02-29 19:09:05.888 10027-10027/k.unionapp D/gralloc_goldfish: Emulator without host-side GPU emulation detected.
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp I/custom_check: The values received in the store part are as follows:
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp I/custom_check: <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant fname - assumed 'fname' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant lname - assumed 'lname' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant fname - assumed 'fname' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant lname - assumed 'lname' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
                                                          <br />
                                                          <b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
                                                          {"fname":"t","lname":"t","email":"t","password":"t"}
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
02-29 19:09:28.450 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at k.unionapp.ServerRequests$getUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:89)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at k.unionapp.ServerRequests$getUserDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:38)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
02-29 19:09:28.451 10027-10413/k.unionapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-29 19:09:28.628 10027-10045/k.unionapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.998ms
02-29 19:09:29.103 10027-10027/k.unionapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**getuserdata.php file:**

```
<?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "uopuser";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user_id, $fname, $lname, $email, $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user[fname] = $fname;
    $user[lname] = $lname;
    $user[email] = $email;
    $user[password] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: your php code likely is producing warnings, and the warning text becomes part of the j output, e.g. `<br>Warning: Foo in Bar[json text here]`. capture the raw response, and see what the error is. I'll bet it's something like undefined index warnings, becdause you're sending over `username/password`, but are looking for `email/password`

Comment: " I am receiving a string that is contaminated with HTML and I have no idea why" - those are php warning messages. `Undefined index: email in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>9</b>`. LIne 9 is `$email = $_POST["email"];`, meaning: there was no POST parameter `email` in that request.

Comment: @kmil post your json, instead of server side code

Comment: Please review my new logcat response, Have changed the username mistake pointed out by David Medenjak

Comment: I agree with Marc B's decision to close this question. Yet there's so much wrong in the php code, it gives me the hibbie jibbies. Please use http://pastebin.com/kZzuZvza as the basis of your php script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error response, probably paired with a non 200 status code.

You require the `email` parameter on your server, but you send `username`. `email` is not found and the php produces an error.

You should add error handling to your server. To fix your issue either change to `username` on your server or `email` in java.

Comment: Many thanks to you & VolkerK! All sorted now.